# Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined in CORDOVA

Tags: android, file, cordova

I've looked into many questions, but those didn't solve my problem.
I've already installed file plug-in.
When I type `cordova plugin ls, I get the following result:

```
[ 'org.apache.cordova.file' ]
```

In androidmanifest.xml I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And in app/res/xml/config.xml I have:

```
<feature name="File">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
</feature>
```

This is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file){
    readDataUrl(file);
    readAsText(file);
}

function readDataUrl(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as data URL");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function readAsText(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as text");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
        document.getElementById('file_status').innerHTML = evt.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}
```

What I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I just struggled a good deal of time with this problem.

The thing, for me, was that ***jQuery document ready events do not fire on Android (Cordova, Phonegap)***, even if you are using the Crosswalk engine!

You have to switch any document ready events to:

Html:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

Js:

```
function onLoad()
{
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
```